# how to add hyperlink to particular node of tree in ext js

Tags: tree, extjs, hyperlink

how to add hyperlink to a particular node of tree in extjs 
can i add hyperlink and how??

Answer (score 7):

Use the `href` config attribute on the node:

```
{
  text: "Go to example.com",
  leaf: true,
  href: "http://example.com"
}
```

Comment: hm didnt even know this existed, nice one ^^ made my post completely worthless :D